# Java-Null Pointer exception in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try to run my `POM(page object model)` for my login page using `Data Driven Framework`, my application has been launched and data has been read but getting `NullPointerException`. 
The data is not being inputted in the username field.

Below is my exception, please help me out but the same code runs properly in my colleague system.

```
FAILED: entercredentials("3019", "India@123")
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
        at PageLibrary.LoginPageNew.Credential(LoginPageNew.java:51)
        at Test.ValidLogin.entercredentials(ValidLogin.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMe



 LoginPageNew.java:51>>> 
public  void Credential(String Ur, String Pd) throws InterruptedException
        {
            //Thread.sleep(20000);
        username.sendKeys(Ur);

    at Test.ValidLogin.entercredentials(ValidLogin.java:54)>>>>>
login.Credential(User,Password);
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trial please?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code and the stack trace, it seems that the User variable that is passed in login.Credential method is null.

Please try and initialize it with some value. Or for debugging purpose just pass some hardcode value in place of User

Comment: i hardcoded but still i get the null pointer exception, will there be any issue in locator

Comment: check that username element is initialized and also check that your driver instance is not null, by printing both these variables.

Comment: will there be any issue on pagefactory intialisation

Comment: yes it can be. If you are not passing your driver instance in action classes, or using driver without initialization, then it will result in null pointer

Comment: how to resolve it, can you please help me out

Comment: post you code please